# Placing three tables in one page

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to place three tables, two in one row and the third one under the first table. Like this:

table1        table2

table3

what I did does this but it doesn't create a space between table1 and table3.

code snippet:

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <form name="" id="tableuser" method="post">
    <table class="one" style="float: left">
      TABLE1
    </table>
  </form>

 <form name="" id="tablegroup" method="post">
   <table class="two" style="float: right">
     TABLE2
   </table>
  </form>
```

```
<div style="display: block;">
 <table class="three" style="float: left">
   TABLE3
 </table>
</div>
```

how can I place the tables in a correct order? thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g72o2s96/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to mention that you shoul use a css file for CSS, and not inline CSS (style and structure should stay separated).

You can do that by adding an other div beetween table 2 and 3:

```
<div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
```

```css
table {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block;">
    <form name="" id="tableuser" method="post">
        <table class="one" style="float: left"><tr><td>TABLE1</td></tr></table>
    </form>
    <form name="" id="tablegroup" method="post">
        <table class="two" style="float: right"><tr><td>TABLE2</td></tr></table>
    </form>
    <div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
    <div style="display: block;">
        <table class="three" style="float: left"><tr><td>TABLE3</td></tr></table>
    </div>
</div>
```